# Creating a Wrapper for TeamCity start script

Tags: teamcity, monit

I am in the process to trying to add TeamCity to a running instance on Monit on our server and have encountered a roadblock that I wonder if anybody else had been able to resolve.  In the examples I have seen, when an app does not create a .pid file when being started this can be done using a wrapper that can do this.  The example on the Monit site are ok, but I wanted to see if anybody had a good TeamCity specific example that I could run with.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Better late then never but you should not need to create a wrapper script as the team city agent generates a pid file.

If you check the bin/agent.sh script you'll see that it outputs a pid file to the logs/ folder. You can use that pid file with monit to monitor the service. You can also edit the shell script to change the location of the pid file.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. "Should" or "should'nt" ? On my freshly installed teamcity 8.0.1 installation, there are absolutely no .pid file in teamcity/logs/ folder for the server itself (started with startup.sh).

Comment: "shouldn't" for the agent, "should" for the server.

Comment: Fixed my poor use of English. I must have been in a hurry. If it does not output the pid file then I'd view the startup.sh script to see what's going on it. You might need to pass it a command line argument to get it to generate a pid file.